how do you pause media on unplugging a usb headset?
I'm using a Arctis nova 3 USB headset on Ubuntu 24.04
when i'm playing music and disconnect my headset the music continues to play
I would like to pause whatever is playing whenever i disconnect my headset

Using the autocomplete of the fish shell i found out that my headset has a systemd device unit called dev-snd-by\\x2did-usb\\x2dSteelSeries_Arctis_Nova_3\\x2d00.device
i managed to create a systemd user service as follows:
[Unit]
Description=Pause Playback
BindsTo=dev-snd-by\x2did-usb\x2dSteelSeries_Arctis_Nova_3\x2d00.device

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=playerctl status
ExecStop=playerctl pause
RemainAfterExit=yes                       

this uses playerctl to pause the playing media on unplug
